# How do i make a video like this

Tags: video

i run a small website and i am interested in making a video like this to promote my website !

The video is on the site http://www.openapps.com/

Any idea which software was used and how I can make it !!

Comment: Hire someone to make it for you.

Comment: [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com) would be better fitted for this question, as SO is programming-related. On the same note, geez people, he just registered ! Give him a break or at least explain why he's getting downvoted.

Comment: @FreekOne  Good to be here. Nice place for all software dev queries.
Isnt SuperUser also programing related ?

Comment: SuperUser, it is for questions about computer hardware and computer software. Explained in greater detail [here](http://superuser.com/faq)

Answer (score 1):

Off-topic, but you need

1. Adobe After Effects or similar compositing application
2. A motion graphics artist

Answer (score 1):

Most likely Adobe After Effects. As for how to make one, don't really expect being able to do do it after watching a couple of tutorials -- for the same quality as the video you mentioned, you definitely need a professional.

Comment: Yeah, either After Effects or Final Cut Pro.  Both are capable of making the referenced video.  I, personally, prefer After Effects